# How to import xlsx to mongodb in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, xlsx

Meteor has mongodb and some module to import xlsx to mongodb.
How can I import xlsx to mongodb in Meteor by mongo-xlsx module?

Comment: Everything is in the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-xlsx) isn't it? If you have a particular issue please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi Damien, Could you please guide me the step by step how to implement it?